# Docker compose Redis and Spring boot app: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)",

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, docker-compose, jedis

Iam working with a Dockerize spring boot application and redis in another container.

I using docker compose to run both containers in the same network, this is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    image: shortenurl
    links:
      - redis
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    networks:
      - redis-net
    depends_on:
      - redis

  redis:
    image: redis
    command: ["redis-server", "--appendonly", "yes"]
    hostname: redis
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    networks:
      - redis-net
    volumes:
      - redis-data:/data

networks:
  redis-net:

volumes:
  redis-data:
```

And this is my application.yml file:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: shortenurl
  redis:
    host: localhost
    port: 6379
```

I've also tried with the redis hots = redis but the result is the same.

My problem is that I'm getting this  java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)" even though the containers are in the same network.

I'm using jedis as the redis client. The issue is in the next method:

[image]

This is  my log:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
app_1    |      at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
app_1    |      at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
app_1    |      at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
app_1    |      at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
app_1    |      at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
app_1    |      at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
app_1    |      at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:184) ~[jedis-2.9.0.jar!/:na]
app_1    |      at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryClient.connect(BinaryClient.java:93) ~[jedis-2.9.0.jar!/:na]
app_1    |      at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.sendCommand(Connection.java:126) ~[jedis-2.9.0.jar!/:na]
app_1    |      at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryClient.incr(BinaryClient.java:228) ~[jedis-2.9.0.jar!/:na]
app_1    |      at redis.clients.jedis.Client.incr(Client.java:158) ~[jedis-2.9.0.jar!/:na]
app_1    |      at redis.clients.jedis.Jedis.incr(Jedis.java:599) ~[jedis-2.9.0.jar!/:na]
app_1    |      at com.neueda.shorturl.repository.ShortURLRepository.incrementID(ShortURLRepository.java:28) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
app_1    |      at com.neueda.shorturl.repository.ShortURLRepository$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$7fae7543.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
app_1    |      at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
app_1    |      at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:746) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
app_1    |      at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
app_1    |      at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
app_1    |      at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
app_1    |      at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
app_1    |      at com.neueda.shorturl.repository.ShortURLRepository$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1e27c0d9.incrementID(<generated>) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
app_1    |      at com.neueda.shorturl.service.URLConverterService.shortenURL(URLConverterService.java:30) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
app_1    |      at com.neueda.shorturl.controller.ShortenUrlController.shortenUrl(ShortenUrlController.java:31) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
app_1    |      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
app_1    |      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
app_1    |      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
app_1    |      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
app_1    |      at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
app_1    |      at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
app_1    |      at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
app_1    |      at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:877) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
app_1    |      at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:783) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
app_1    |      at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
app_1    |      at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
app_1    |      at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
app_1    |      at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
app_1    |      at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:877) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
app_1    |      at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
app_1    |      at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
app_1    |      at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
app_1    |      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
app_1    |      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
app_1    |      at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
app_1    |      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
app_1    |      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
app_1    |      at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:90) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.4.RELEASE]
app_1    |      at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
app_1    |      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
app_1    |      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
app_1    |      at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
app_1    |      at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
app_1    |      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
app_1    |      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
app_1    |      at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
app_1    |      at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
app_1    |      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
app_1    |      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
app_1    |      at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
app_1    |      at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
app_1    |      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
app_1    |      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
app_1    |      at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:155) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.4.RELEASE]
app_1    |      at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:123) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.4.RELEASE]
app_1    |      at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:108) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.4.RELEASE]
app_1    |      at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
app_1    |      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
app_1    |      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
app_1    |      at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
app_1    |      at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
app_1    |      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
app_1    |      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
app_1    |      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
app_1    |      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
app_1    |      at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
app_1    |      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
app_1    |      at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
app_1    |      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
app_1    |      at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
app_1    |      at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
app_1    |      at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
app_1    |      at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:800) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
app_1    |      at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1471) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
app_1    |      at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
app_1    |      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_111]
app_1    |      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_111]
app_1    |      at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
app_1    |      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_111]
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: how do you initialize `Jedis`? please attach the Jedis client configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to connect to `redis` host in Jedis client and `application.yaml` of your spring boot app

```
Set<HostAndPort> jedisClusterNodes = new HashSet<HostAndPort>();

jedisClusterNodes.add(new HostAndPort("redis", 6379));
```

Comment: what to do in case of using jedisconnectionfactory?